# Que argumentos debe tener la funcion que maneja transaction en laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

espero me puedan ayudar, no se como usar la transacción, lo estoy haciendo desde el registerControler que te genera Auth.

La transacción funciona cuando hay un error, como por ejemplo matricula o correo repetido, y la información del formulario nunca llega a la base de datos, el problema es cuando la información si esta toda correcta, me general el siguiente error.

"Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection as array"

Entonces aquí mi problema es que no estoy pasando correctamente los datos, CREO...

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    DB::transaction(function ($data) {

        return usuarios::create([
            'matricula' => $data['matricula'],
            'nombres' => $data['nombres'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'apellPat' => $data['apellPat'],
            'apellMat' => $data['apellMat'],
            'facultad' => $data['facultad'],
            'areaCono' => RegisterController::buscarArea($data['facultad']),
            'genero' => $data['genero'],
            'tipoUsuario' => 2,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer parámetro de `transaction()` es un `closure` (en tu caso la función que estás creando), pero esa función no lleva parámetros.

Si lo que querés hacer es acceder a `$data` dentro de la función, utilizá `use`.

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso es lo que buscaba, ya no me da error con los datos, (lo se porque también lo use en otro controlador). Pero ahora me da otro error y creo que es porque hace uso del "return" lo cual la verdad no entiendo... eso lo creo laravel cuando hice uso del comando " php artisan make:auth " espero me puedas ayudar en esa parte.

Comment: Qué error te aparece? Por defecto Laravel usa el modelo `User` vos estás usando `usuarios`. Publicá el error y el archivo entero así se entiende mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya resolvi el problema. `codigo`

Answer (score 0):

Así quedo el código para que pudiera usar $data y regresar la respuesta. Muchas Gracias **azeós**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $resp = DB::transaction(function () use($data) {
        $respuesta = usuarios::create([
            'matricula' => $data['matricula'],
            'nombres' => $data['nombres'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'apellPat' => $data['apellPat'],
            'apellMat' => $data['apellMat'],
            'facultad' => $data['facultad'],
            'areaCono' => RegisterController::buscarArea($data['facultad']),
            'genero' => $data['genero'],
            'tipoUsuario' => 2,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        return $respuesta;
    });
        return $resp;
}
```

Comment: Que bien ver ya tienes la solución, recuerda que para indicar si la pregunta esta resuelta puedes marcar como aceptada la publicación que consideres como la respuesta correcta